# Why ncurses prints 7+ same consecutive characters as a single character?

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main() {
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    //  6 xs
    printw("xxxxxxx");
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
xxxxxx
```

If I add just one more x to the `printw` statement only

```
x
```

is printed. Why?

OS: *Arch Linux*

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce here (I get 7 `x`). This is on what OS, using which terminal?

Comment: Solved by `putenv("TERM=vte")` based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162793/different-ncurses-behaviours-with-different-terminals

Comment: Even though I marked the question as solved  I would still be interested in the reason of this behavior.